# targets/stm32f1x.cfg:74: Error: target requires -dap parameter instead of -chain-position! OpenOCD

Tags: stm32, openocd

I am using OpenOCD to flash code into a black-pill (STM32f103). It worked a week ago but after updating ubuntu (it's the only thing I can think of that changed) it gives me an error when flashing the code.

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0-rc2
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
WARNING: interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg is deprecated, please switch to interface/stlink.cfg
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
targets/stm32f1x.cfg:74: Error: target requires -dap parameter instead of -chain-position!
in procedure 'script' 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 26
at file "black_pill.cfg", line 24
at file "targets/stm32f1x.cfg", line 74
```

The stm32f1x.cfg file content:

```
# script for stm32f1x family

#
# stm32 devices support both JTAG and SWD transports.
#
source [find target/swj-dp.tcl]
source [find mem_helper.tcl]

if { [info exists CHIPNAME] } {
   set _CHIPNAME $CHIPNAME
} else {
   set _CHIPNAME stm32f1x
}

set _ENDIAN little

# Work-area is a space in RAM used for flash programming
# By default use 4kB (as found on some STM32F100s)
if { [info exists WORKAREASIZE] } {
   set _WORKAREASIZE $WORKAREASIZE
} else {
   set _WORKAREASIZE 0x1000
}

#jtag scan chain
if { [info exists CPUTAPID] } {
   set _CPUTAPID $CPUTAPID
} else {
   if { [using_jtag] } {
      # See STM Document RM0008 Section 26.6.3
      set _CPUTAPID 0x3ba00477
   } {
      # this is the SW-DP tap id not the jtag tap id
      set _CPUTAPID 0x1ba01477
   }
}

swj_newdap $_CHIPNAME cpu -irlen 4 -ircapture 0x1 -irmask 0xf -expected-id $_CPUTAPID

if { [info exists BSTAPID] } {
   # FIXME this never gets used to override defaults...
   set _BSTAPID $BSTAPID
} else {
  # See STM Document RM0008
  # Section 29.6.2
  # Low density devices, Rev A
  set _BSTAPID1 0x06412041
  # Medium density devices, Rev A
  set _BSTAPID2 0x06410041
  # Medium density devices, Rev B and Rev Z
  set _BSTAPID3 0x16410041
  set _BSTAPID4 0x06420041
  # High density devices, Rev A
  set _BSTAPID5 0x06414041
  # Connectivity line devices, Rev A and Rev Z
  set _BSTAPID6 0x06418041
  # XL line devices, Rev A
  set _BSTAPID7 0x06430041
  # VL line devices, Rev A and Z In medium-density and high-density value line devices
  set _BSTAPID8 0x06420041
  # VL line devices, Rev A
  set _BSTAPID9 0x06428041
}

if {[using_jtag]} {
 swj_newdap $_CHIPNAME bs -irlen 5 -expected-id $_BSTAPID1 \
    -expected-id $_BSTAPID2 -expected-id $_BSTAPID3 \
    -expected-id $_BSTAPID4 -expected-id $_BSTAPID5 \
    -expected-id $_BSTAPID6 -expected-id $_BSTAPID7 \
    -expected-id $_BSTAPID8 -expected-id $_BSTAPID9
}

set _TARGETNAME $_CHIPNAME.cpu
target create $_TARGETNAME cortex_m -endian $_ENDIAN -chain-position $_TARGETNAME

$_TARGETNAME configure -work-area-phys 0x20000000 -work-area-size $_WORKAREASIZE -work-area-backup 0

# flash size will be probed
set _FLASHNAME $_CHIPNAME.flash
flash bank $_FLASHNAME stm32f1x 0x08000000 0 0 0 $_TARGETNAME

# JTAG speed should be <= F_CPU/6. F_CPU after reset is 8MHz, so use F_JTAG = 1MHz
adapter_khz 1000

adapter_nsrst_delay 100
if {[using_jtag]} {
 jtag_ntrst_delay 100
}

reset_config srst_nogate

if {![using_hla]} {
    # if srst is not fitted use SYSRESETREQ to
    # perform a soft reset
    cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
}

$_TARGETNAME configure -event examine-end {
    # DBGMCU_CR |= DBG_WWDG_STOP | DBG_IWDG_STOP |
    #              DBG_STANDBY | DBG_STOP | DBG_SLEEP
    mmw 0xE0042004 0x00000307 0
}

$_TARGETNAME configure -event trace-config {
    # Set TRACE_IOEN; TRACE_MODE is set to async; when using sync
    # change this value accordingly to configure trace pins
    # assignment
    mmw 0xE0042004 0x00000020 0
}
```

I've tried changing the -chain-position for -dap but as I don't understand what I am doing it doesn't work.

Any help helping me understand this error would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 0.11.0 OpenOCD doesn't create the DAP(Debug Access Point) isn't automatically created. Change the line for:

```
dap create dap_name -chain-position $_TARGETNAME
target create $_TARGETNAME cortex_m -endian $_ENDIAN -dap dap_name
```

For more information:
https://openocd.org/doc/html/TAP-Declaration.html#dapdeclaration